# The (adjective) (noun) Enigma vs The (adjective) (noun)'s Enigma

Tags: word-choice

This is the title of a short story I'm writing:

> The Washing Machine Enigma

But I was wondering if I should call it

> The Washing Machine's Enigma

Do both mean the same? Which one follows more proper English?

Comment: You should probably add a hyphen in the first one: *The Washing-Machine Enigma.*

Comment: If you are writing *Big Bang Theory* fanfic, definitely the first choice is better.

Comment: @MετάEd Ha, why a Big Bang Theory fanfic?

Comment: @Cerberus Unless of course what's involved is the extraordinary machine invented by Turing's colleague Washing, which contributed so critically to breaking the Enigma code.

Comment: @StoneyB: Hmm my irony detector has a a day off today, and I lack any knowledge about Turing's colleagues...but then I'd call it *Washing's Machine Enigma*, if *Machine Enigma* means anything (it can't be *Washing's Machine called Enigma, after all). I read it as simple an enigma concerning one or more washing machines.

Comment: @alexchenco Because of the way they name the episodes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*The Washing Machine Enigma* is an enigma which somehow involves a washing machine.

*The Washing Machine's Enigma* would be an enigma which confronts or baffles a particular washing machine. That strikes me as unlikely -- unless of course the Washing Machine is a technical consortium which carries out money laundering for organized crime and terrorism.